# How to run tests with JUnit and Ant? In the same JVM or different JVM?

Tags: java, ant, junit, jvm

I am facing a small problem with JUnit and Ant. I do not know how I should run tests. Should I use the `forked="yes"` option witch make a new VM for each test,or should I use the same VM?

Which is the better way, or how do I know when to use the same JVM or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To run JUnit tests in Ant use the [`junit`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task. There is an option to run the tests in a separate JVM (the `fork` attribute).

In general, it is better to run the tests in a separate VM to isolate them from the Ant JVM and its classpath. This also allows to configure properties of the JVM for the tests, like the maximum amount of memory (many attributes of the task are only applied if `fork` is enabled).

However, this makes the tests take longer because of the overhead of creating a new JVM. This also depends on the `forkmode` attribute. If set to `perTest`, each test will run in its own VM.

**`forkmode`**

> Controls how many Java Virtual Machines get created if you want to fork some tests. Possible values are "perTest" (the default), "perBatch" and "once". "once" creates only a single Java VM for all tests while "perTest" creates a new VM for each TestCase class. "perBatch" creates a VM for each nested  and one collecting all nested s.

Comment: I want to know witch is the best way to run tests.In a separate JVM or in the same JVM .

Comment: @Luci "Best" isn't meaningful without any context.

Comment: I know that, but I just wanted to see how the two alternatives looks like.

Comment: @manouti So,If a use let's say forked=true and also use timeout,when the specified timeout expires the JVM will be killed ? (Considering that forkmode="perTest")

Comment: Yes it will. The [task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) mentions this: _"If a forked test runs into a timeout, Ant will terminate the Java VM process it has created"_.